# split a string column into row and delete the original row - postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am an amateur in postgresql and I am looking to split a comma delimited column into many columns. I managed to split my column into rows and insert new rows based on the number of separated strings with this code

```
INSERT INTO myTable (username, town)
SELECT 
    username, 
    regexp_split_to_table(town, E',') 
FROM myTable;
```

Now what I want to achieve is, to remove the original column from database. Any advice would be appreciated.

[This SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/796567/14) shows what I done so far!

Comment: No primary key in the table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well it is just a fiddle. But I really don't know. Is it really neccesary? Would that help? And how?

Comment: It would help in deleting those unwanted rows later.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Aha! And how exactly? sorry I'm a newbie in this field. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way would be to simply delete those rows that contain a `;`. No new row can contain the delimiter as it won't be returned by `regexp_split_to_table()`.

```
delete from yourtable
where town like '%;%';
```

Assuming there was a (generated) primary key in the table (e.g. named `id`) another option would be to use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with old_data as (
  select id, username, town
  from yourtable
), new_data as (
  -- this will generate new primary key values not present in "old_data"
  insert into yourtable (username, town)
  select username, regexp_split_to_table(town, ';')
)
delete from yourtable
where id in (select id from old_data);
```

---

<sup>Your SQL Fiddle and your question are inconsistent. The fiddle uses `,` but your question uses `;` as a delimiter. I used `;` to be consistent with your question</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the time. I'm really grateful for the help. I wasn't familiar with the "with" syntax and should learn it but it helped me to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply flag the "old records" then delete them and remove all the flags like so:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN new BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;
INSERT INTO yourTable (username, town, new)
SELECT 
    username, 
    regexp_split_to_table(town, E','),
    true
FROM yourTable;

DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE new = false;

ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN new;
```

Comment: Thank you for the time. It really helped!

Comment: It's a little easier to comprehend than the solution utilizing `with`